# Accessing TRAC attachments with php script

Tags: php, export, attachment, trac

We are in process of migrating off of TRAC issue tracker. One piece that is proving hard to work around is exporting or even accessing attachment files from a PHP script.

For example, when a user clicks a filename in trac it takes them to a page

```
https://example.com/trac/attachment/ticket/12345/somerandomfile.txt
```

This page then shows a viewer with the file shown inside the viewer. There is not a direct link to the file anywhere. Searching the filesystem for somerandomfile.txt yields no results.

There is not a path in the trac `attachment` table. Attachments on the filesystem appear to be stored in a trac/files/attachments/ticket/ folder, with a ton of subfolders that look a little like:

```
drwxrwx---. 3 apache apache  54 Oct 14  2014 ed2
drwxrwxr-x. 3 apache apache  54 Jun 27  2016 efe
drwxrwxr-x. 3 apache apache  54 Apr 27  2016 f03
drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache  54 Sep  5  2023 f23
drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache  54 May 16  2022 f27
etc
```

Inside one of those folders, f27 for example, is the following:

```
ll trac/files/attachments/ticket/f27/f272a53b0ef1c576ff83d5cbdb2278970c863fb8/

-rw-r--r--. 1 apache webdev 136822 May 16  2022 3ae453533caeb7abb4a407d28beb556d58e8db04.png
```

I found a [script](https://github.com/mavam/trac-hub/blob/master/tools/extract-trac-attachments.sh) that exports attachments to a dedicated trac/$ticketID/ folder, however it is very slow running and seems to have stopped altogether.  The script uses trac-admin for the exporting process.

Is there a simpler/better/faster way to directly access trac's attachment files via PHP?

Comment: I'm assuming there's an htaccess file somewhere that is routing this to a specific script that perform logic, can you post that?

Comment: There are [trac-admin](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin#FullCommandReference) commands to list and export attachments. If you want to operate directly on the database, you could run some queries on the [attachments](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema/Attachments#Tableattachment) table. You'll need to use some API functions to get the path on the filesystem so it's a little bit complex. If you want to go that route, I suggest asking on the [trac-users mailing list](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).